# Display data through chart control C#

Tags: c#, charts

I've got a datagridview that get populated from CSV file. I now want to represent the data in the table. I've tried some code but it doesn't work. I want it to draw the chart, after the button has been pressed.

Here is my whole code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public class HRData
        {
            public int? HeartRate { get; set; }
            public int? Speed { get; set; }
            public int? Power { get; set; }
            public int? Altitude { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return String.Format("Heart rate={0}, Speed={1}, Power={2}, Altitude={3}", HeartRate, Speed, Power, Altitude);
            }
        }   

        public static class HRDataReader
        {
            static private int? ConvertValue(string[] values, int index)
            {
                if (index >= values.Length)
                    return null;
                int value;
                if (int.TryParse(values[index], out value))
                    return value;
                return null;
            }

            static public IList<HRData> Read(string fileName)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
                {
                    string line;

                    // First: Skip to the correct section.
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        if (line == "[HRData]")
                            break;

                    // Now: Read the HRData
                    List<HRData> data = new List<HRData>();
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (line.StartsWith("[") && line.EndsWith("]"))
                            break;
                        line = line.Trim().Replace("\t", " "); // Remove all tabs.
                        while (line.Contains("  ")) // Remove all duplicate spaces.
                        line = line.Replace("  ", " ");
                        string[] values = line.Split(' '); // Split the line up.
                        data.Add(new HRData
                        {
                            HeartRate = ConvertValue(values, 0),
                            Speed = ConvertValue(values, 1),
                            Power = ConvertValue(values, 2),
                            Altitude = ConvertValue(values, 3)
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();

                IList<HRData> data = HRDataReader.Read(openFileDialog1.FileName);

                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "HeartRate", HeaderText = "Heart rate", DataPropertyName = "HeartRate" });
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Speed", HeaderText = "Speed", DataPropertyName = "Speed" });
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Power", HeaderText = "Power", DataPropertyName = "Power" });
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Altitude", HeaderText = "Altitude", DataPropertyName = "Altitude" });

                dataGridView1.DataSource = data;

                //int 
                int maxSpeed = data.Max(x => x.Speed.Value);
                maxSpeed = maxSpeed / 10;
                string MaxSpeed = Convert.ToString(maxSpeed);
                textBox1.Text = MaxSpeed;

                double aveSpeed = data.Average(x => x.Speed.Value);
                aveSpeed = aveSpeed / 10;
                aveSpeed = Math.Round(aveSpeed, 0);
                string AveSpeed = Convert.ToString(aveSpeed);
                textBox2.Text = AveSpeed;

                double aveHeart = data.Average(x => x.HeartRate.Value);
                aveHeart = Math.Round(aveHeart, 0);
                string AveHeart = Convert.ToString(aveHeart);
                textBox3.Text = AveHeart;

                int maxHeart = data.Max(x => x.HeartRate.Value);
                string MaxHeart = Convert.ToString(maxHeart);
                textBox4.Text = MaxHeart;

                int minHeart = data.Min(x => x.HeartRate.Value);
                string MinHeart = Convert.ToString(minHeart);
                textBox5.Text = MinHeart;

                double avePower = data.Average(x => x.Power.Value);
                avePower = Math.Round(avePower, 0);
                string AvePower = Convert.ToString(avePower);
                textBox6.Text = AvePower;

                int maxPower = data.Max(x => x.Power.Value);
                string MaxPower = Convert.ToString(maxPower);
                textBox7.Text = MaxPower;

                double aveAltitude = data.Average(x => x.Altitude.Value);
                aveAltitude = Math.Round(aveAltitude, 0);
                string AveAltitude = Convert.ToString(aveAltitude);
                textBox8.Text = AveAltitude;

                int maxAltitude = data.Max(x => x.Altitude.Value);
                string MaxAltitude = Convert.ToString(maxAltitude);
                textBox9.Text = MaxAltitude;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chart1.DataSource = hRDataBindingSource;
            chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = Speed;
            chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "test";
            chart1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "it doesnt' work" - Sigh, what doesn't work? What output do you get, and what did you expect to get?

Comment: At the moment, I don't see any graph. Just red X across the space where it meant to be. I want to see something like a line graph with the "Speed" from my datagridview.